# Firebase Remote Config App Version condition comparison

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm using Firebase Remote Config, and I'm trying to wrap my head around the App Version conditions.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/parameters#rule_types says I must do String matching on it.

But I really need a way to say parameter_x will have different values on different version ranges.

Is there any way to do this, or am I stuck coming up with a ridiculous regular expression?

Comment: I'm not sure why they went with `versionName` and not `versionCode`. It would be so much simpler to compare. If it's of any help, you can use comma separated values, and just list the versions you want to be included.

Comment: The problem with that is you have to make sure you update it with every release.  I want it to take a certain value on all versions greater than X, without having to update that condition all the time.

But yes, `versionCode` would be great.

Answer (score 4):

the comparison operators for `app version` are limited (because of strings, eg `0.0.1-alpha5`):

> for string values: `contains`, 
>   `does not contain`, `exactly matches`, `regular expression`

while an `(int) versionCode` could be defined & compared as a `user property`:

> for numeric values: `=`, `≠`, `>`, `≥`, `<`, `≤`

appending the build flavor to the `versionName` might be the most simple.